# Why does a UIStackView with a single view, fill Proportionally, and Layout Margins causes ambiguous constraint error?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, uistackview

The following code is an attempt to add a UIStackView to a view controller, pinned on all edges with a little margin, and add a label to it.

I want the StackView to use `.fillProportionally` as its distribution mode ready for when I add more views into it later on.

It seems that for a **single arranged subview** whenever the distribution mode is  **`.fillProportionally`** and **layout margins** are used then I get an ambiguous constrain error (below). What is the cause of this error?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    label.text = "ABC"

    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label])
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
    stack.layoutMargins = .init(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    view.addSubview(stack)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        stack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
        stack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
    ])
}
```

}

Abiguous constraint error ([WTFAutoLayout](https://www.wtfautolayout.com/?constraintlog=(%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a432f0%20%27UISV-canvas-connection%27%20UILayoutGuide:0x6000000f3100%27UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide%27.leading%20%3D%3D%20UILabel:0x7ff470913280%27ABC%27.leading%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a423f0%20%27UISV-canvas-connection%27%20UILayoutGuide:0x6000000f3100%27UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide%27.trailing%20%3D%3D%20UILabel:0x7ff470913280%27ABC%27.trailing%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a425d0%20%27UISV-fill-proportionally%27%20UILabel:0x7ff470913280%27ABC%27.width%20%3D%3D%20UIStackView:0x7ff46d510030.width%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a77f70%20%27UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint%27%20H:%7C-(10)-%5BUILayoutGuide:0x6000000f3100%27UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide%27%5D(LTR)%20%20%20(active,%20names:%20%27%7C%27:UIStackView:0x7ff46d510030%20)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a42940%20%27UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint%27%20H:%5BUILayoutGuide:0x6000000f3100%27UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide%27%5D-(10)-%7C(LTR)%20%20%20(active,%20names:%20%27%7C%27:UIStackView:0x7ff46d510030%20)%3E%22%0A))):

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a432f0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000000f3100'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == UILabel:0x7ff470913280'ABC'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a423f0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000000f3100'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == UILabel:0x7ff470913280'ABC'.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a425d0 'UISV-fill-proportionally' UILabel:0x7ff470913280'ABC'.width == UIStackView:0x7ff46d510030.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a77f70 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(10)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000000f3100'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7ff46d510030 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a42940 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000000f3100'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(10)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7ff46d510030 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a423f0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x6000000f3100'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == UILabel:0x7ff470913280'ABC'.trailing   (active)>
```

Comment: Did you ever find an approach to this?  Whilst I understand DonMag's excellent explanation below of why this is happening, I can't begin to think of how to fix it or workaround it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Editing with clarification because my original answer was not entirely correct...*

First, the `.fillProportionally` distribution property of a `UIStackView` is very often misunderstood.

Second, we get some oddities when a stack view's distribution is `.fillProportionally` ***and*** the stack view's `.spacing` is not `0`, or when the stack view ***also*** has `.layoutMargins` set.

The problem you're hitting is the way auto-layout calculates the proportional sizing.

Based on experimentation, auto-layout calculates the proportional widths of the views and *then* applies the layout margins, ***subtracting*** from the width of the last view to accommodate the space.

This can be easily demonstrated as follows:

[image]

There are 6 horizontal stack views, each set to 200-pts wide, Distribution set to `.fillProportionally`, and filled with either one or two views. The Red views have an intrinsic width of 25, the Green views 75.

The first stack view, with a single view and no layout margins, fills the width as expected... the red view takes up 100% of the space.

The second stack view, with two views and no layout margins, also fills as expected... the red view is 50-pts wide (25%) and the green view is 150-pts wide (75%).

The third stack view, though, starts showing the problem. The single view is give a proportional width of 100%, or 200-pts... but then the layout margins are applied. This shifts the view 10-pts from the left, but because auto-layout doesn't subtract space from the *first* subview, it actually extends 10-pts past the edge of the stack view (so the red view is *still* 200-pts wide).

The fourth stack view *looks* like it's doing what we want... proportional fill with 10-pts margin on each side... the Red view is 50-pts wide (25% of 200) ***but*** the Green view is only 130-pts wide. So auto-layout gave the two views 50-pts (25%) and 150-pts (75%) but ***then it applied the margins*** and took the 20-pts away from the Green view.

Using layout margins of `left: 100 right: 0` or `left: 0 right: 100` for the bottom two stack views makes it much more obvious. Again, for each of those, Red gets 50-pts (25%) and Green gets 150-pts (75%), but then the margin of 100-pts gets stripped from Green.

---

So, to answer the original question about why we get ambiguous constraints when we have a single arranged subview ***and*** layout margins, look at stack view 3. Auto-layout could not manage to give Red 100% of the space ***and*** apply margins, so it throws the layout error.

---

Here's the code to run the above example. If you comment-out the third stack view, you *won't* get the error:

```
class ProportionalStackExampleViewController: UIViewController {

    let outerStackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.spacing = 8
        return v
    }()

    let outerStackFrame: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        return v
    }()

    let infoLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .light)
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.text = "Red views have intrinsic width of 25\nGreen views have intrinsic width of 75\nAll horizontal stack views are 200-pts wide\nTap any view to see its width"
        return v
    }()

    let sizeLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.text = "(width)"
        return v
    }()

    let myGreen = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.75, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for _ in 1...6 {
            let lbl = UILabel()
            lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .light)
            lbl.numberOfLines = 0
            lbl.textAlignment = .center
            outerStackView.addArrangedSubview(lbl)
            let sv = UIStackView()
            sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            sv.axis = .horizontal
            sv.distribution = .fillProportionally
            sv.spacing = 0
            outerStackView.addArrangedSubview(sv)
        }

        view.addSubview(infoLabel)
        view.addSubview(sizeLabel)
        view.addSubview(outerStackFrame)
        view.addSubview(outerStackView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            sizeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: infoLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            sizeLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),

            outerStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sizeLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            outerStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            outerStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),

            outerStackFrame.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerStackView.widthAnchor),
            outerStackFrame.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerStackView.heightAnchor),
            outerStackFrame.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerStackView.centerXAnchor),
            outerStackFrame.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: outerStackView.centerYAnchor),
        ])

        // StackView 1
        if let lbl = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[0] as? UILabel,
            let sv = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[1] as? UIStackView {

            lbl.text = "One view, no layoutMargins"

            var v = ProportionalView()
            v.w = 25.0
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            sv.addArrangedSubview(v)

            var tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showWidth(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(tg)

        }

        // StackView 2
        if let lbl = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[2] as? UILabel,
            let sv = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[3] as? UIStackView {

            lbl.text = "Two views, no layoutMargins"

            var v = ProportionalView()
            v.w = 25.0
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            sv.addArrangedSubview(v)

            var tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showWidth(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(tg)

            v = ProportionalView()
            v.w = 75.0
            v.backgroundColor = myGreen
            sv.addArrangedSubview(v)

            tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showWidth(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(tg)
        }

        // comment out this block to see the auto-layout error goes away
        // StackView 3
        if let lbl = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[4] as? UILabel,
            let sv = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[5] as? UIStackView {

            lbl.text = "One view\nlayoutMargins left: 10 right: 10"

            var v = ProportionalView()
            v.w = 25.0
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            sv.addArrangedSubview(v)

            sv.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
            sv.layoutMargins = .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)

            var tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showWidth(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(tg)

        }

        // StackView 4
        if let lbl = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[6] as? UILabel,
            let sv = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[7] as? UIStackView {

            lbl.text = "Two views\nlayoutMargins left: 10 right: 10"

            var v = ProportionalView()
            v.w = 25.0
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            sv.addArrangedSubview(v)

            var tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showWidth(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(tg)

            v = ProportionalView()
            v.w = 75.0
            v.backgroundColor = myGreen
            sv.addArrangedSubview(v)

            sv.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
            sv.layoutMargins = .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)

            tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showWidth(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(tg)
        }

        // StackView 5
        if let lbl = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[8] as? UILabel,
            let sv = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[9] as? UIStackView {

            lbl.text = "layoutMargins left: 100 right: 0"

            var v = ProportionalView()
            v.w = 25.0
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            sv.addArrangedSubview(v)

            var tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showWidth(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(tg)

            v = ProportionalView()
            v.w = 75.0
            v.backgroundColor = myGreen
            sv.addArrangedSubview(v)

            sv.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
            sv.layoutMargins = .init(top: 0, left: 100, bottom: 0, right: 0)

            tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showWidth(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(tg)
        }

        // StackView 6
        if let lbl = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[10] as? UILabel,
            let sv = outerStackView.arrangedSubviews[11] as? UIStackView {

            lbl.text = "layoutMargins left: 0 right: 100"

            var v = ProportionalView()
            v.w = 25.0
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            sv.addArrangedSubview(v)

            var tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showWidth(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(tg)

            v = ProportionalView()
            v.w = 75.0
            v.backgroundColor = myGreen
            sv.addArrangedSubview(v)

            sv.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
            sv.layoutMargins = .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 100)

            tg = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showWidth(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(tg)
        }

    }

    @objc func showWidth(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        if let v = sender.view {
            sizeLabel.text = "Width: \(v.frame.width)"
            sizeLabel.textColor = v.backgroundColor
        }
    }

}

class ProportionalView: UIView {
    var w: CGFloat = 1.0

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: w, height: 40.0)
    }

}
```

Comment:  What an excellent answer. This is exactly the insight I was missing, thank you!

Comment: Great explanation.  I've been trying to understand this for days.  I have a similar scenario although it's with inner stack views that have multiple subviews but when embedded inside a scrollView and then added to a viewController as a childVC, the proportional constraints start breaking. Still have no idea how to fix but at least I understand why it's breaking

Comment: @Anthony - when you say *"the proportional constraints start breaking"* ... do you mean subview constraints proportional to each other? Or are you trying to use `Fill Proportionally` on stack views?

Comment: @DonMag - I've tried laying it out in different ways.  The best seems to work but gives me UISV-spacing constraint conflicts. Happy to share code, raise seperate question or DM

Comment: @Anthony - either post it as a new question or post the code somewhere (GitHub, pastebin, etc) and I'll take a look.

Comment: @DonMag - thanks.  Posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66646871/why-do-embedded-uistackviews-filled-proportionally-with-spacing-and-layout-ma

Comment: @DonMag - not sure if you saw but would really appreciate some help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of `label` to `false`.

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Since you want to set all the `layoutMargins` to `10`, the `width` and `height` of `stack` can not be equal to `view's` `width` and `height`.

You need to accommodate that difference of 20 (both sides) in `width` and `height`.

So the `constraints` should be,

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    stack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    stack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: -20),
    stack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: -20),
])
```

Also, the margin spacing is included within the constraints, there is no need to write the below code. So remove it.

```
stack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
stack.layoutMargins = .init(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I'm particularly looking for a solution to the implications of Layout Margins and fillProportional rather than a way of working around it.
For example if I were trying to achieve the same layout by subclassing UIStackView instead of embedding it then I wouldn't want to touch the width and height constraint's constants